# Is there a way to cube a large sequence of integers?

Tags: r

I am new to R. I am attempting to create a vector containing the cubic of integers from 1:10000. When I try using the cube function that I made with the sapply function. It works fine with smaller numbers, but I cannot figure out how to make it work with larger numbers.

Here is my code:

```
n <- 10000

cube <- function(x){
return(x*x*x)
}

vec <- c()
vec <- sapply(seq_len(n), cube)
print(vec)
```

I expected to get a vector containing, vec(1^3, 2^3, ..., 10000^3)

But instead I am getting an incredible number of this error:

Warning in x * x * x : NAs produced by integer overflow
Warning in x * x * x : NAs produced by integer overflow
Warning in x * x * x : NAs produced by integer overflow
Warning in x * x * x : NAs produced by integer overflow

Comment: `(1:n) ^ 3` works

Comment: No need for `sapply`, R vectorization will handle this. `x <- (1:10000)^3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many workarounds for this issue (>32-bit integers); here is a potential solution using the [bit64 package](https://rdrr.io/cran/bit64/man/bit64-package.html)

```r
library(bit64)
#> Loading required package: bit
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'bit'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     xor
#> Attaching package bit64
#> package:bit64 (c) 2011-2017 Jens Oehlschlaegel
#> creators: integer64 runif64 seq :
#> coercion: as.integer64 as.vector as.logical as.integer as.double as.character as.bitstring
#> logical operator: ! & | xor != == < <= >= >
#> arithmetic operator: + - * / %/% %% ^
#> math: sign abs sqrt log log2 log10
#> math: floor ceiling trunc round
#> querying: is.integer64 is.vector [is.atomic} [length] format print str
#> values: is.na is.nan is.finite is.infinite
#> aggregation: any all min max range sum prod
#> cumulation: diff cummin cummax cumsum cumprod
#> access: length<- [ [<- [[ [[<-
#> combine: c rep cbind rbind as.data.frame
#> WARNING don't use as subscripts
#> WARNING semantics differ from integer
#> for more help type ?bit64
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'bit64'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     :, %in%, is.double, match, order, rank

n <- 10000

cube <- function(x){
  bigx <- as.integer64(x)
  cubed <- bigx * bigx * bigx
  return(cubed)
}

vec <- c()
vec <- lapply(1:n, cube)
head(vec)
#> [[1]]
#> integer64
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> integer64
#> [1] 8
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> integer64
#> [1] 27
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> integer64
#> [1] 64
#> 
#> [[5]]
#> integer64
#> [1] 125
#> 
#> [[6]]
#> integer64
#> [1] 216
tail(vec)
#> [[1]]
#> integer64
#> [1] 998500749875
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> integer64
#> [1] 998800479936
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> integer64
#> [1] 999100269973
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> integer64
#> [1] 999400119992
#> 
#> [[5]]
#> integer64
#> [1] 999700029999
#> 
#> [[6]]
#> integer64
#> [1] 1000000000000
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>